# How to Convert "Android Open Source Project App" to Gradle Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-source

It's my first time seeing a Project but it's not look like Android Studio Project i've seen before.

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Music
```

my friend send me this and i want to develop it like i always doin'. but it cannot. cuz its not Gradle Project. So, how can i convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, how can i convert it?

You can't. AOSP [doesn't use Gradle](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/build/building) as build system.

Answer (score 2):

I agree AOSP does not use Gradle however there is AIDEGen that helps you prepare parts of AOSP for editing through Android Studio or IntelliJ.

[AIDEGen](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/asuite/+/refs/heads/master/aidegen/README.md)

This tool is far from perfect, but gives you a starting point to edit and make change to the source files. You'll have to keep using Android build system. Finally, this tool is Android 10 +

[AOSP Other Tools](https://source.android.com/docs/setup/download#other-tools)