# How to Build Android Open Source Project (AOSP) files in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-source

I am trying to open some Android Open Source Project (AOSP) files in Android Studio.

I have cloned my desired directory with:

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support`

When I open android studio and try to build the project I get error in the gradle-wrapper.properties file:

```
The specified Gradle distribution 'file:/C:/Users/MyUserName/AndroidStudioProjects/platform-frameworks-support/support/gradle/wrapper/../../../../tools/external/gradle/gradle-8.0-bin.zip' does not exist.
```

I have tried to workaround this by changing the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties file to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip`. However this throws another error:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
> Could not find com.gradle:gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin:3.12.2.
  Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Users/MyUserName/AndroidStudioProjects/prebuilts/androidx/external/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.12.2/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.12.2.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/MyUserName/AndroidStudioProjects/prebuilts/androidx/external/com/gradle/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin/3.12.2/gradle-enterprise-gradle-plugin-3.12.2.jar
  Required by:
      unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
> Could not find com.gradle:common-custom-user-data-gradle-plugin:1.7.2.
  Searched in the following locations:
    - file:/C:/Users/MyUserName/AndroidStudioProjects/prebuilts/androidx/external/com/gradle/common-custom-user-data-gradle-plugin/1.7.2/common-custom-user-data-gradle-plugin-1.7.2.pom
    - file:/C:/Users/MyUserName/AndroidStudioProjects/prebuilts/androidx/external/com/gradle/common-custom-user-data-gradle-plugin/1.7.2/common-custom-user-data-gradle-plugin-1.7.2.jar
  Required by:
      unspecified:unspecified:unspecified
```

How can I successfully build the AOSP platform-frameworks-support code in Android Studio 2022.1.1 on Windows 10?

Comment: Development of those libraries is not supported on Windows, sorry.  You can use a Linux VM, though.  Follow the instructions here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/HEAD/docs/onboarding.md to get set up on Linux or macOS.

Comment: @RyanM What if i am using Windows Subsystem for Linux in my Android Studio. i.e. In Android Studio Terminal i enter 'bash' to change my terminal to [accept Linux commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36365641/15597975). Will it work then?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74141580/how-to-convert-android-open-source-project-app-to-gradle-android-studio/74141718#74141718

Comment: @mars8 I'm not sure.  It's not officially supported, but...it might work?  You might need to launch the Linux version of Android Studio from within WSL via the `./studiow` script (otherwise you're stuck setting up Studio yourself, which is probably doable, if annoying).  I'm curious to hear how it goes, if you try!

Comment: You will, at the very least, need more repositories checked out than just that one.  The conventional (supported) technique uses the `repo` tool to do this, which doesn't work on Windows.  That's the major blocker here.   It is possible to do this with pure `git` (someone on the team works this way) but I don't know if there are public instructions on doing it.

Comment: thanks @RyanM. I also saw there was a [github repo](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_support) that mirrored aosp however it hasn't been updated for 5 years...